# Suggestion of a Data Structure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, pseudocode

Regarding this question:

You are given an unsorted array A of n integers in the range 2^n −10n ≤ A[i] ≤ 2^n.
Suggest a data structure that allows to answer in O(1) steps the number of keys in the range a to
b (note that a, b are not necessarily integers). The construction of data structure should
cost at most O(n) steps.

1. Describe in few sentences the data structure.
2. Write a pseudocode for constructing the data structure.
3. Write a pseudocode for the numberKeys(NewDataStructure,a,b).
4. Give a short explanation of the time and space complexity of (2) and (3).

Can someone please explain me what `the number of keys in the range a to b` means?

Appreciate your help!

Thanks!

Comment: (Coincidence on CS@SE: [Explaining a question in Data Structure](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/140377/19966).)

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/140377/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/67555435/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 2):

Let's say `n=1000`

Then you have an array of `1000` entries (=keys, integer values, numbers, ...) within the interval
`[2^1000-10000;2^1000]`.

A question could be:
How many array entries are in interval `[2^1000-9321.7;2^1000-123.2]`?

Comment: Thank you! What do you mean by array entries?

Comment: "Array entries in interval `[2^1000-9321.7;2^1000-123.2]`" means elements in the array whose value is within the range of `2^1000-9321.7 to 2^1000-123.2`.

Answer (score 1):

> "the number of keys in the range a to b" means DS must be able to answer range based query at any point time for any range. Like if there are 10 entries then find entry with value greater than 5 but less than 7.

> Describe in few sentences the data structure.

Binary search tree based structure will work with each not having link to child node and a extra variable tracking range of child nodes.

Refer [Binary search tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-tree-set-2-properties/)

Time to find the range node O(n).
Time to find number of node in range is O(1) as we are going to calculate while building/creating the tree.